# Does Summon Eidolon bring your Eidolon to full health?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The description of the spell says that it can be summoned even if it is sent away due to the damage.

> You open a rift between dimensions that summons your eidolon.

Treat this as if you had summoned your eidolon normally, except that it only remains with you for the duration of this spell. While summoned in this way, your eidolon cannot touch any creature warded by protection from evil or a similar effect and your eidolon can be sent back to its home plane by dispel magic.

If you cast this spell while your eidolon is already on your plane, this spell has no effect. This spell allows you to summon your eidolon even if it has been returned to its home plane due to damage.

Does this mean my Eidolon is healed of damage when it is summoned?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually covered by implication in the [Eidolon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/#TOC-Eidolon) rules themselves, where it says, in part...

> The only exception to this is if the eidolon was slain, in which case it returns with half its normal hit points. The eidolon does not heal naturally.

So, generally, in any case where the Eidolon is summoned after being killed, it will be on half hit points. This paragraph goes on to say that, if killed, it cannot be summoned until the following day. The Summon Eidolon spell is breaking this last restriction only.